# Is Firebase considered as front-end side?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, frontend, backend

Firebase works with AngularJS and AngularJS is front-end. Firebase also doesn't have table nor SQL nor a relation. Me and my friend keep arguing about this problem. He said that Firebase belongs to back-end cuz it is a kind of Database

Comment: Firebase is considered a "back-end as a service" (or BaaS), since most of it runs on Google's servers. But it allows you to build full client-side apps, without writing server-side code. Trying to classify technologies is a great way to spend an evening with (geek) friends, but it's too opinionated to fit well on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank mate! now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) is a database, which is technically the part where you store/access data ([data access layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)). So technically, it should belong on the backend side.